# VB.NET LINQ Query to build string of properties

Tags: vb.net, linq

How can you make this loop faster. With 4000 objects in resultData this loop takes too long to execute.

I tried a Linq query to do the same but it is not working.

Original Code:

```
For Each a As AjaxSubmissionOverview In resultData
    submissionIDs += a.Submission_ID.ToString() + ","
Next
```

Linq Replacement:

```
submissionIDs = From s In resultData Select s.Submission_ID.ToString() + ","
```

Comment: I recommend just selecting the IDs as an array of integer and if you need them as a concatenated string, only after the loop join them into one string when needed. Anyway 4000 objects in any array is very large amount, I suspect you need some other way completely to implement what you need if you want efficiency.

Comment: If you don't end up using String.Join, note that to build a string from a lot of pieces you should use a StringBuilder: [Using the StringBuilder Class in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```vb
Imports System.Linq
/* ...
... */
Dim submissionsCsv As String = String.Join(",", resultData.Select(Of String)(Function(x) x.Submission_ID).ToArray())
```

Comment: Thank you this works great and has made a massive performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Dim submissionIDs As String = String.Join(",", resultData.Select(Function(x) x.Submission_ID))
```

Comment: Error 14 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Select' can be called with these arguments:
    Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of AjaxSubmissionOverview, Integer, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

Comment: `x => x.Submission_ID` is c# syntax.

Comment: @pmortlock Use `Function(x) x.Submission_ID` instead of `x => x.Submission_ID`, and if you're using a recent version of VS then you don't need the `.ToArray()`.

Comment: Thank you this works great and has made a massive performance improvement